# Azure app service deployment failing The subscription 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm

Tags: azure, web-applications, terraform, appservice

Hi I'am having issues with deploying the app service through azure portal and terraform.

When I try to deploy the service I get this error The subscription 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm. But 2 days ago I was able to deploy without any issues.

I checked on github and azure learn but had no luck, does anyone have any idea why it's not working?

**[fixed]**

Hey everyone,
Just wanted to give you a quick update – the issue seems to have resolved itself. I reached out to the Azure support team and had a couple of conversations with them over the last three days. We went through the classic troubleshooting steps like changing the plan, resource group, and location, but unfortunately, nothing seemed to help.
Interestingly, I decided to try deploying again through the Azure portal every morning to see if there were any changes. Yesterday, to my surprise, the deployment went through successfully. Sometimes, things just work out on their own!
Thanks for your support and suggestions.

Comment: Can you check the comment from this link and check the troubleshoot steps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1545914/web-app-deployment-failing-the-subscription-xxxx-i

Comment: Hey, I tried all of that.
subscription is active
I tried logging in and out from both cli and portal, still have the same issue

Comment: Did you also check the quota on your subscription?

Comment: I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1527674/the-subscription-is-not-allowed-to-create-or-updat, and it seems that you need to raise a Microsoft support request to fix it. Can you please give a shot?

Comment: Can you share the terraform code here? @ViniciusDeschamps

Answer (score 0):

> The subscription 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm:

***Need to check below:***

- Make sure that you are attempting to create or update both the service plan and app service in the same region to prevent conflicts.
- Verify the existence of any Azure Policies created by other users that might impact or restrict the creation or modification of the server farm or related resources.
- Check the providers list and register `Microsoft.Web` provider if is not existed with the help of below CLI commands.

`az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Web`

```bash
az provider list --query "[namespace=='Microsoft.Web'].resourceTypes[].resourceType"
```

[image]

- Clear all the logged in subscriptions cache using [`az account clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-clear) command and set the required subscription freshly using `az account set --name` command. Now if required login into Az account with `az login` command.
- Verify the Terraform code configuration and ensure that the `app_service_plan_id` is accurately defined and associated with the identical resource group as the `App Service`.

After checking all the above, I tried deploying an app service in a dedicated app service plan and the deployment was successful as shown below.

Template taken from [`azurerm_app_service`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service) terraform registry.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features  {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "examplejahresources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "jahplan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "jahservice"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
  }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "Database"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=some-server.mydomain.com;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  }
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[Reference](https://video2.skills-academy.com/en-us/answers/questions/1539331/app-service-deployment-error-the-subscription-is-n) discussion for the relevant issue.

Comment: Hi Jahnavi thanks for answering, I followed your steps and still have the same issue. I tried my tf code on another subscription and it works smoothly. I would agree with @ViniciusDeschamps that this is probably an issue on azure side. Yesterday I wrote them a ticket and had a conversation with a support person hopefully they will get back to me today with some answers!

Comment: It might be the subscription issue only then. Have you tried logging out of it and logged in again? @flicko

Comment: Yeah a couple of times, changed the bowsers too...  @Jahnavi

Comment: In that case, you have to raise a support ticket as you did. Usually the above options mentioned in my answer should be helpful if it is related to your environment but not from Azure side. @flicko